# CWinAppEx - overloading LoadState()

Tags: mfc, load, state, mdi

I have an MFC MDI application that annoyingly loads up the previous state of toolbars, etc, when I run it.  I've set

```
 m_bSaveState = FALSE;
```

in the App constructor ... but it had no effect.  So I've attempted to overload the LoadState() method as in:

```
    // added this to the MainApp.h file
virtual BOOL LoadState(CWnd* pFrame, LPCTSTR lpszSectionName = NULL );
```

and ...

```
 // added the following to the MainApp.cpp
 BOOL CDrumGenMDIApp::LoadState (CWnd* pFrame, LPCTSTR lpszSectionName )
{
// do nothing to pre-load the state from the Registry
return TRUE;
 }
```

... however this method appears never to be called.  When the system is loading Frames I'm pretty sure it is calling some profile of LoadState() ... but how do I get it to call my overloaded method?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the header file, the function you are trying to override is not declared virtual nor does it exist?!

However the following function is virtual:

```
  virtual BOOL LoadState(LPCTSTR lpszSectionName = NULL, CFrameImpl* pFrameImpl = NULL);
```

I have not tried this myself, but it should work in theory.